# Git pull in working directory tree of a teammate on windows7 LAN share

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-pull

My teammates only has read-access to remote repo's (no write to remotes). so, they pull latest from bitbucket, make updates/changes, mail or manually send over the changed files, which I overwrite in my copy of repo (in working directory), review their work (changes) before committing and finally pushing to Bitbucket.

I tried setting a remote pull across LAN, `git pull origin master` over a windows7 LAN-share but that only works if teammates commit to their local repo which is not what I want.

I want to pull in the working directory files from teammates so that I can review those changes, commit changes and then push to remote.

Is there a way with git to pull in working directory tree of my teammates in LAN or any other workflow suggestions that would help me achieve eliminate the manual file sharing/copying in my repo.

I have GIT version 2.13.0.windows.1

thanks
appu

Comment: So you want to pull changes that are not even commited yet? How about your teammate commits them. After that you can pull them and reset the commits. The files will stay the same and you can write new commits.

Comment: yes, I want to pull that's are NOT committed by teammates cause if they commit and I pull from their local repo and upon review if required i'd need to make another commit if required (after review), that creates 2 commits for one task, basically I want to avoid that and a single commit after review.

Comment: @frieder, can u tell how resetting the commit will work while the file stays the same. AFAIK, if you reset to a previous commit, the working directory files are reverted to their state prior to last commit.

Comment: `git reset HEAD~~~` where the number of `~`s is the number of commits you want to go back. As far as I know the files should not be changed as long as you are not using the `--hard` flag.

Comment: Yup that should work. However, does the orphaned commit goes into remote repo as well. If yes, how to avoid it. thanks...

Comment: No it wont because you removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about your teammate commits all his changes so you can pull them.

After pulling all changes it is possible to reset the repo to a previous commit by using `git reset HEAD~~~` where the number of `~`s is the number of commits you want to go back. The files will stay unchanged unless you are using the `--hard` flag.

Now you can re-commit all changes by yourself.

The orphaned commit will not be pushed to the remote repository because it is not part of your repository anymore.